# Confusion caching Active Record queries with  Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

My version is:

- Rails: 3.2.6
- dalli: 2.1.0

My env is:

- config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
- config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211', {:namespace => 'MyNameSpace'}

When I write:

```
 Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
     User.where('status = 1').limit(1000)
 end
```

The user model can't be cached. If I use

```
 Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
     User.all
 end
```

it can be cached. How to cache query result?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason is because

```
User.where('status = 1').limit(1000)
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is actually a scope, not a query. Rails caches the scope.

If you want to cache the query, you need to use a query method at the end, such as `#all`.

```
Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
  User.where('status = 1').limit(1000).all
end
```

Please note that **it's never a good idea to cache ActiveRecord objects**. Caching an object may result in inconsistent states and values. You should always cache primitive objects, when applicable. In this case, consider to cache the ids.

```
ids = Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
  User.where('status = 1').limit(1000).pluck(:id)
end
User.find(ids)
```

You may argue that in this case a call to `User.find` it's always executed. It's true, but the query using primary key is fast and you get around the problem I described before. Moreover, caching active record objects can be expensive and you might quickly end up filling all Memcached memory with just one single cache entry. Caching ids will prevent this problem as well.

Comment: thx. If I have a category model, it may have less then 100 records, I cache Category.all is a good idea? not cache the cateogry id

Comment: Or I first change Category.all to json, and cache them in memcached?

Comment: This is a very important and subtle issue; we just realized this issue had been creeping in to our app -- the difference between `Foo.where(bar: 'fubar')` and `Foo.where(bar: 'fubar').all` is completely different w/r/t caching, and something that can easily and subtly slip into your codebase.  Check and check regularly if you rely on caching.

Comment: Good explanation of why caching may not always be a good idea. One issue I ran into is that cached results aren't upgraded during a migration unless you explicitly expire the cached objects as part of the migration. For instance, if you add a migration that adds a new field with a default value and pass in `:null => false` (effectively upgrading all the rows in the table with the default value), records from the cache will return a nil value, not the default, until you expire the cached records and force them to be fetched again.

Comment: As always with caching you should also be very aware of your invalidation/sweeping plan.

Comment: I'd like more evidence that it's *never* a good idea to cache ActiveRecords (even though the alternative of `find(ids)` is quite quick anyway, as you point out). Especially if they're being used read-only for display purposes - perhaps the most common usage - I'm not sure it can do much harm in most cases. Perhaps there's some risk of broken links if an association changes, requiring some case-by-case analysis, but I think that's rare in reality.

Comment: me too @mahemoff i read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) `Sometimes you need to cache a particular value or query result instead of caching view fragments. Rails' caching mechanism works great for storing *any* kind of information.` I assume query result would include ActiveRecord::Relations and 'any' is in bold

Comment: So if we want to cache an ActiveRecord::Relation on `find()`, what can we use?  My find query is expensive, I want to cache it -- nobody has answered how I can do it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to selected answer: for Rails 4+ you should use `load` instead of `all` for getting the result of scope.

Comment: `User.find(1).load` gives me `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)` on Rails 4.1.15

Answer (score 2):

`Rails.cache.fetch` caches exactly what the block evaluates to.

```
 User.where('status = 1').limit(1000)
```

Is just a scope, so what gets cached is just the ActiveRecord::Relation object, ie the query, but not its results (because the query has not been executed yet).

If you want something useful to be cached, you need to force execution of the query inside the block, for example by doing

```
User.where('status = 1').limit(1000).all
```

Note that on rails 4 , `all` doesn't force loading of the relation - use `to_a` instead

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
User.where("status = 1").limit(1000).all
```

should work.