# Rails.cache - working but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

I am using Rails.cache (I have tried both default store and memcached with the dalli gem - but I get the same behaviour) it *seems* to be working, but isn't (logs show that the query is not made, but actual results show otherwise)... I have a search page that caches the top ten queries for 1 day:

search.rb

```
  def self.top_ten
    Rails.cache.fetch("top_ten_searches_cache", :expires_in => 1.day) do
      Search.order("count DESC").limit(10)
    end    
  end
```

However, when I go to the search page, and enter a new search term, repeatedly, it begins to show in the top ten results! (Whereas I am not expecting the top ten results to change until 1 day passes.) When the cache store is default, no query shows in the log (so you think cache is working) and when using dalli/memcached I get exactly the same behaviour, but with this in the log:

```
Cache read: top_ten_searches_cache ({:expires_in=>1 day})
Cache fetch_hit: top_ten_searches_cache ({:expires_in=>1 day})
```

What does `Cache fetch_hit` mean exactly? Could it mean that no cache was found and is having to do the query?

Not really sure what's going on - it's odd that I get the same behaviour with either the default store or memcached with Dalli.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're caching the scope, not the actual results of the query. Rails uses lazy loading, so to force the query to execute you need to put `.to_a` (or `.all` in Rails 3), for example:

```
def self.top_ten
  Rails.cache.fetch("top_ten_searches_cache", :expires_in => 1.day) do
    Search.order("count DESC").limit(10).to_a
  end    
end
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221230/1520714).

Comment: Hi Mike - thanks, how could I forget that! I have changed the query as per your example, however, I am still getting the same behaviour - if I search for a new term around five times it shows up in the top-ten list, and I'm not expecting that to change for 24 hours (as it should be returning the cached value). Am I doing anything else wrong?

Comment: Ah I think I know what's going on... I need to refresh the cache as it's holding the old value...