# caching activerecord results just like fragments

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, memcached

In my views I do a lot of this:

```
<% cache("sports_menu_" +session[:lang], {:expires_in => 60.minutes}) do %>
...... # a load of stuff
<% end %>
```

However I've discovered a lot of time is spent querying the DB for data that doesn't change that often. **Is there a way to cache this data in a similar manner?**

For instance:

```
Model.find(:all, :select => "only a few fields", :conditions => "nasty conditions", :include => "some joins", :order => "date_time desc")
```

This takes about 7 seconds, the main table keeps about 20M records. A lot of users hit this particular action and the query only runs once/hit. But it would make sense caching that for a number of minutes so that for everyone else it will load from the cache. I'm using memcache by the way.

I can't cache the entire action because there are some parameters that change on occasion and some locale-specific code within the view.

I have considered moving that to the view level but don't feel too comfortable about that, it would kind of defeat the point of using Rails.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like [ActiveRecord::Cache::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html) is what you want.  You can use it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218917/confusion-caching-active-record-queries-with-rails-cache-fetch).

Comment: I've used similar to this before, and it worked quite nicely.

Comment: Well, took some time figuring out how to implement this in my crazy particular case but now these site pages that were taking 7-10 seconds now load in an instant :) Thank you so much for pointing this out.