# Rails caching all query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have that kind of script.

Search_controller.rb :

```
def results
   @users = @search.cached_users_count.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end
```

Search.rb Model :

```
users = users.order('current_sign_in_at DESC')  


def cached_users_count

    Rails.cache.fetch(["user_count", expires_in: 5.minutes]) { users }

end
```

What i want to do is cache all query because when some user will login after search results are executed, will_paginate replace results on next page - because just logged user go on first position and results are changed for order by current_sign_in_at

Can somebody help me with that ? Right now no cache is made , for every search results theres is sql response.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to change in your current implementation to get the behavior you're looking for.

1. The `users` object you're starting with is returning a relation, but
   only the scope, which means it is not storing results as you expect.
   To store the results of the query you'll need to load them using a
   query method. Use `all` if in Rails 3, or `load` if in Rails 4:

   ```
   users.order('current_sign_in_at DESC').all  #Rails 3
   users.order('current_sign_in_at DESC').load #Rails 4, all is deprecated
   ```
2. The syntax for the Rails cache is incorrect if you really want it to
   expire. You're passing `expires_in` as part of the key, which is an
   array `[]` in your current code. You want to just pass normal
   parameters, with `expires_in` as an option.

   ```
   Rails.cache.fetch("user_count", expires_in: 5.minutes) { users }
   ```

See the following for a similar question on SO as well:
[Confusion caching Active Record queries with  Rails.cache.fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218917/confusion-caching-active-record-queries-with-rails-cache-fetch)