# Rails 4 - Low-level Caching Still Querying Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, activerecord

I'm following the [low-level caching tutorial found on Heroku's website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#low-level-caching). Copying their example almost word-for-word, here is my method:

```
def Trip.test_low_level
  Rails.cache.fetch("test_destinations", expires_in: 12.hours) do
    Trip.all.joins(:destinations).where("destinations.id = ?", 382)
  end
end
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should:

1. Execute the query the first time `Trip.test_low_level()` is called
2. The second time `Trip.test_low_level()`, it should look for the cache called 'test_destinations' and return the result **without querying the database**.

However, no matter how many times I run the method, the query is still called. Here are results from my terminal.

```
Trip.test_low_level()
  Trip Load (6.2ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" INNER JOIN "destination_orders" ON "destination_orders"."trip_id" = "trips"."id" INNER JOIN "destinations" ON "destinations"."id" = "destination_orders"."destination_id" WHERE (destinations.id = 382)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Trip id: 2783, title: "Test Saving"....


Trip.test_low_levle()
  Trip Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" INNER JOIN "destination_orders" ON "destination_orders"."trip_id" = "trips"."id" INNER JOIN "destinations" ON "destinations"."id" = "destination_orders"."destination_id" WHERE (destinations.id = 382)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Trip id: 2783, title: "Test Saving"
```

Even if I call the cache directly, I get the same result:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('test_destinations')
  Trip Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" INNER JOIN "destination_orders" ON "destination_orders"."trip_id" = "trips"."id" INNER JOIN "destinations" ON "destinations"."id" = "destination_orders"."destination_id" WHERE (destinations.id = 382)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Trip id: 2783, title: "Test Saving"...
```

How can I prevent it from hitting the database the second time?

**EDIT: Here is my settings in development.rb**

```
# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

**Production.rb**

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Comment: Could it be that the cache is not used in dev?

Comment: Development definitely performs fragment caching as I've already implemented that. Edited my post with my other settings.

Comment: what is your setting for `production.rb`?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, maybe its because '.where' returns a scope. Is there any difference if you explicity load it with '.to_a'?

Comment: Just tested - adding .to_a doesn't change the result. @HieuPham, I edited my response with my production settings. How would that affect development though?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218917/confusion-caching-active-record-queries-with-rails-cache-fetch

Comment: Ahh! @FrederickCheung, that was the key. I searched SO and couldn't find other questions that helped. What is the etiquette for selecting an answer on this thread?