# Query still getting logged as slow-query in mysql server in Rails app even after enabling low level caching

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have recently added low level caching to a query in Rails 3.2.14 app. In my local I do not see the cached query running twice but its getting logged in production.

I have even checked answers given on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218917/confusion-caching-active-record-queries-with-rails-cache-fetch) where it talks about converting the query result to an array using `to_a` method.

```
@top_quiz_creators = Rails.cache.fetch("/quiz/creators", expires_in: 1.hours) do
   Quiz.find_by_sql("some complex query").to_a
end
```

In mysql-slow.log:

```
# Time: 170118  8:28:32
# User@Host: db[db] @ ip-xyz.ec2.internal [xyz]
# Query_time: 5.403992  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 10272991
SET timestamp=1484728112;
```

How can I stop this query from hitting DB again and again?

Comment: Caching isn't going to speed up your query.

Comment: @shmosel yes that's true but I want to reduce the hits. Right now its running every second I just want to run it once every hour across sessions as it is leaderboard related. I am also working on optimizing the query but I want to know why does it get logged. Why production and development are having this difference?

Answer (score 1):

To speed up your query have to keep two things in your mind

1. First implement the foreign keys and indexes in the database level
2. And use ActiveRecord wisely

Comment: I have added indexes on all the tables required in this query. Now the queries takes .22 seconds to run and now due to some reason it is not getting logged. I did not do any change to the query.

Comment: So I think its better no?? previously I was taking 5.403992 seconds? Anyway.. also add the foreign key if needed

Comment: If you found this useful could you please upvote this?